# Can I inline a function partially/selectively?

Tags: c, inline, c99

```
void run_hot(void) {
    // I am called very often!
    serve();
    // <more code here>
}

void run_cold(void) {
    // I am called only occasionally!
    serve();
    // <more code here>
}

???inline??? void serve(void) {
    // I only want to be called inline from hot functions!
    // <more code here>
}
```

Is there any way to explicitly inline a function *A* in a function *B* while explicitly *not* inlining the same function A in a function *C*? Or am I completely at the mercy of my compiler?

Comment: You can inhibit inlining by putting a function in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: If you don't want that a function is inlined, put the definition in a separate .c file and compile it separately.

Comment: You'd put `run_hot` with `inline` in a .h file such that it is visible for everybody. You'd put only the prototype of `run_cold` (without `inline`) in that same .h file. Then you create a .c file that contains `extern inline run_hot(void);` to "instantiate" your inline function and a definition of `run_cold`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are completely at the mercy of the compiler with inlining.
Leave aside partially, whether or not to `inline` a function is solely a decision that is best made by the compiler and you should rely on it to make the best decision.

Comment: @Will If you are using GCC, you can use `__attribute__((hot))` to tell the compiler to optimize that function more, so it wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @WillBuddha: There is also profile-guided optimization (where you compile and run the program instrumented to generate profile data, then feed that profile data back into the compiler for the optimised build).  See the [`-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use` options to GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: @caf That might be an even better solution! Cheers!